# npm install -g cordova and ionic 2 error

Tags: cordova, npm, installation, ionic2

I'm trying to install ionic 2 for some hours and I don't succee.
while I'm install cordova by cmd with the command "npm install -g cordova"
I get this error

```html
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Adir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-ed18b12b
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-ed18b12b' -> 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-ed18b12b' -> 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adir\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

when i install ionic by this command "npm install -g ionic"
I get this error

```
npm WARN In ionic@2.0.0 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
```

npm WARN In ionic@2.0.0 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.0.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-75d35ef1
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-75d35ef1' -> 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-75d35ef1' -> 'C:\Users\Adir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adir\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Answer (score 3):

seems like you have some version mismatch issue. so download latest node,install latest npm and start afresh.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm cache clean
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm intsall -g cordova
```

Comment: spelling mistake for UNINSTALL & INSTALL

Comment: still help me to fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

What fixed my problem was I tried unistalling and re-installing node via brew in mac
`npm cache clean` 
`brew uninstall --force node`
`rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
`brew install node`

Now if you run "which node"
It should `/usr/local/bin/node`

And now set NODE_PATH in my .bash_profile as 
`export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

After this it gave me no problem what so ever

Answer (score 1):

The checksum failed npm ERR! shasum check failed

You can try upgrading to the latest version of npm :

```
npm install -g npm
```

To upgrade to npm 3.

Also :

```
npm cache clean
```

and

```
enter code here
```

npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
1 - Install the latest version of NodeJS from their website (e.g. 6.X.X).
2 - Open the Node.js command prompt as administrator.
3 - Run: npm cache clean
4 - Run: npm uninstall -g ionic
5 - Run: npm uninstall -g cordova
6 - Run: npm install -g ionic
7 - Run: npm install -g cordova
```