# Error installing ionic on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

```
C:\Program Files>npm install -g ionic cordova
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

`-- ionic@2.1.4

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"    "cordova"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-514e00ac
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-514e00ac' ->     'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ab brev'
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-514e00ac' ->  'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
 npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
 npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
 npm ERR! enoent
 npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\npm-debug.log.3790864127
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\npm-debug.log.3790864127'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\npm-debug.log.3790864127'
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\npm-debug.log.3790864127' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\npm-debug.log
```

I have been trying to install ionic on my windows laptop. Before installing ionic on my laptop, I installed nodejs. But after that, everytime I try to install ionic, it shows this error on my command prompt. I also looked for similar problems on this website as well as other but couldn't find any that actually solves my problem. I also looked at [npm install -g cordova and ionic 2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572918/npm-install-g-cordova-and-ionic-2-error[installing) ionic on window 10][1]
but the solution provided there would not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Follow These Steps:-

1- First check that you have the latest node version.
2- Then search for Command Prompt and **RUN IT AS ADMINISTRATOR.**
3- then type the above commands :-

```
 npm install -g ionic 
    npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

Open nodejs command prompt with administrator permission, redirect to c:> drive, then try same command which you used.

> npm install -g ionic cordova

If you still getting the error, then it may be the problem with your node version [here is link to refer about this issue and answer from ionic team](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8196)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling my nodejs and then installing the new one, nodejs v 5.11